Incorrect positioning of tour button
Take the tour is floating at the wrong place.

The position varies by a few pixels from time to time. 
My browser is Chromium Version 25.0.1364.160 on Ubuntu 12.04.
Observed on multiple sites which have long blurbs.

https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/helpcenter
https://russian.stackexchange.com/helpcenter
https://spanish.stackexchange.com/helpcenter


It's possibly a little too close to the bottom than intended in Chrome stable - but not reproducing this. What browser are you using?

Reproduced in IE9 - That looks like an older version of Chrome though.

@TimPost Its the one present in repo for 12.04 LTS, so its gonna be around for awhile in Ubuntu-verse.

I checked - and the issue here seems to be that the text about the site is sufficiently long to push the button down. We're going to have to look and see where else this might be happening - stay tuned.

@TimPost Changing the entire blurb was rather unexpected!

Wat? It's Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for researchers and developers who explore the principles of a system through analysis of its structure, function, and operation. It's 100% free, no registration required. - I don't see what changed?

@TimPost See answer below.

The blurb has been changed making it of almost constant length for all sites. 


That's the help center, not the same as new users see when they land on the front page. I see where the confusion was :) Yes, initially we just duplicated the hero that all new users see on the front page, but always with the intention of making that one more help center specific.
